# Ridge Regression: Ridge traces are barely change across different k values [EDIT]

Tags: ridge-regression

I am working with Matlab and following the example laid out here:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ridge.html

I then use the code above on my own data (with ~ 80 features). However, no matter what k values I select (from extremely small to extremely large), the traces remain constant.

[image]

Any suggestions as to what I could be doing wrong? I don't believe it's a scripting issue. Could it be something to do with my data?

Thank you.

EDIT: after looking into the exact traces, they are changing over k, but by very small amounts. Any ideas as to what in my data could be leading to such behaviour?

Comment: The scale of the ridge parameter $x$ is from 0 to $10^5$. Are you sure that plotting over such a wide range isn't suppressing any change in the standardized coefficient axis $y$?

Comment: Hi Sycorax, thanks for the suggestion. I have also tried to plot over a small range of extremely small k values and I get the same thing unfortunately.

Comment: If you use the data from the Matlab example, but with your code,  do you observe the same behavior or different behavior? It seems if there's no bugs in the code, you should be able to exactly reproduce the Matlab plot using the same data.

Comment: So I have looked further into the plots, and the traces actually are changing, but by extremely small values as k changes, which gives the appearance of a flat/no change line. Any idea as to why my data is leading to such rigid traces?

Comment: I don't. You should [edit] your question to reflect your new understanding & new questions based on what you've learned from your investigation.

Comment: Will do, thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: could you define what a standardized coefficient is?

Comment: How many observations? The penalty is taken against the likelihood. Likelihood too big? No penalty affecting output yet.

Comment: I have 133 observations to go along with 85 features.